# Devise error using rails 3.0.1 on sign_in action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm developing a rails 3 app using rails 3.0.1 and I'd like to use devise for user auth, but when I login with a user email, I get this error:

> RuntimeError in Devise/sessionsController#create
>
> In order to use `respond_with`, first you need to declare the formats your controller responds to in the class level

I installed devise using Gemspec.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue yesterday and today i up a ticket and they fix the problem. Make a bundle update to have the fix version.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure this is the *first* entry in your routes file

   devise_for :users
2. Consider upgrading to Rails 3.0.3